# Alternative to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I've been looking around and am a bit lost on this topic. People have said that there's alternatives to iframes, but I don't see any that fit the bill for what I'm trying to do. I essentially created a small game that uses videos and plays particular ones based on corret button input from the keyboard.

All of that is in a seperate html file, and I want to display it on a different html file to be in an iframe like state on a different webpage. But I can't seem to figure out the best approach to this.

The iframe is just too slow, the game itself runs fine, but when I put it in an iframe it lags like crazy half the time, or stuff doesn't render because it's going so slowly.

Any ideas of where to start?

Comment: I think you can use div instead of iframes, and fill divs with ajax calls.

Comment: What makes you think that the `<iframe>` slows things down?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is one alternative to `<iframe>` and that's the `<object>` tag. It can display content from different sources as well. The pro is it being conform to the xhtml-standards and encouraged to use  but there's not such a broad / usable support in older browsers (you have to mess with it to get it right in IE). It's used as followed:

```
<object data="page.html" width="400" height="300" type="text/html">
    Alternative Content
</object>
```

That being the direct answer to you question I don't think it will give you any speed advantage. Already for the reason that the `<iframe>`-element is much more used and so more tested and cared for than `<object>`.

I for myself never saw an `<iframe>` being the cause for a slowdown, but that still might be possible. If that is an option, you should definitely try what *ocanal* said before in the comments: Let your script work on an wrapper container-div instead of the body-element and so embed it directly on the mainpage.

For the browser it shouldn't be much more than some overhead from handling a second document, so you could guess that it's just that little more to make your pc run slow. So it might be a good idea to optimize the code in general:

1. Look if you can find the bottleneck causing the slowdown. Possible causes could be

   - altering the DOM a lot - which is always slow
   - acting a lot on things not even visible on screen
   - getting attributes from objects. For every additional period you use it means more work for your cpu:

     ```
     // instead of using this over and over again
     house.roof.window.handle.open();
     house.roof.window.handle.close();

     // save it to a var and use that instead
     var handle = house.roof.window.handle;
     handle.open();
     handle.close();
     ```
2. Updating the game in short equal intervals by `window.setTimeout()` may also be too fast and waste cpu power unnecessarily (or too slow and won't look fine then, but never really right) - so you can use the new [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame). The vendor-prefixed variants are implemented in the current versions of all important browsers and it's easy to provide a fallback to the old method.
3. As a last thought: Maybe it even helps in some meta-magical way to include the script file itself on the mainpage and not in the embeded document

Comment: can i use this in place of iframe in sending email via AWS?

Comment: How would one load external content using just a div?